# Styling MathJax

Tags: html, css, mathjax

I'm so confused about this.  I've searched for tutorials but can't find any that make much sense to me, how do I set a CSS class for MathJax output?  I just want to make the font big.  The current include is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

At the bottom of my page.  Renders TEX fine, but I'd like to set some CSS on it!

Ideally I'd like to pass a CSS class name to it.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `scale` option in your output processor?  See [the manual](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/1.1/options/HTML-CSS.html).  You can set the configuration options either in a file or inline; [this page](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/1.1/configuration.html#configuring-mathjax) covers the process.

Basically, you include a short snippet of JavaScript in your page, or in a file you include.  Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
  MathJax.Hub.Config({    
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],    
    "HTML-CSS": { scale: 100}    
  });    
</script>
```

Also, you can simply surround the thing in a `div` with a CSS class applied.  View the source on [this page](http://www.mathjax.org/demos/scaling-math/).

```
<div style="font-size: 500%;">    
\[

  g\frac{d^2u}{dx^2} + L\sin u = 0

\]    
</div>
```

The equation will simply inherit the font size.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't work out where to set these options, I'm completely lost

Comment: I added a link to another page that covers that process.

Comment: I've been through those web pages, that one you linked to doesn't show me how to change the font size.

Comment: It absolutely does.  It says to set the scale option.  It shows you how to set the scale. The last one I linked has an even simpler solution with an enclosing `<div>`.

Comment: Ok thanks, but that last link was added in after my last comment, sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that; I noticed the example under the "demos" section after I posted the link to the configuration manual.  I will say that it's worth learning to use the configuration files, though; there are many options you can set.

Answer (score 13):

**Update:**

As I have learned now, do **not** use CSS to style TeX in mathjax, it could lead to display problems. See here: https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/925

Solution is to use Javascript with the Config block:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config"> 
    MathJax.Hub.Config({ 
        "HTML-CSS": { scale: 200, linebreaks: { automatic: true } }, 
        SVG: { linebreaks: { automatic:true } }, 
        displayAlign: "left" });
</script>
```

---

**Obsolete:**

I am loading MathJax dynamically with JQuery's getScript(), only in case there are `$$` on the page. In this case the solution above does not work.

The workaround is to set the CSS after the loading took place:

```
$(".MathJax").css("font-size","150%");
```

Instead of the font size in `%` you can also use `px` or `em`.

If this does not work, use !important for your CSS styles. For instance:

```
.MathJax, .MathJax_Display  {
    text-align: left !important;
    font-size: 130%  !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Works fine on all browsers I tested except Safari on a mobile device.  Is there a way to get font size changes to work in that context?  **EDIT:**  Answered my own question less than a minute after posting this, as I am so prone to do for some reason.  Basically just add another line inside MathJax.Hub.Config:  `CommonHTML: { scale: 150, linebreaks: { automatic: true } },`

Comment: Hi, thanks. It looks like `CommonHTML: { scale: 150, linebreaks: { automatic: true } },` can scale the math, but strange `"HTML-CSS": { scale: 200, ...` does not works on my Markdown editor(ghostwriter)

Comment: Doesn't work for me due to inline style: `<span id="MathJax-Element-3-Frame" class="mjx-chtml MathJax_CHTML" tabindex="0" style="font-size: 121%; ...</span>`. If I do Ctrl-F5 in Chrome, font size is 101%; just F5 it's 121%.