# html jquery Mathjax increase font-size with text

Tags: jquery, html, css, mathjax

I try increase font-size Mathjax and text.
So, my situation is this.

Click the "Up" button --> Use jquery, add font-size css

```
.importantRule { font-size:500% !important; }
$("#jax").addClass('importantRule');
```

but result is strange. Picture this:

[image: original size picture]

[image: increase font-size 500% picture]

I found a problem: fraction line is thin and not bold.
I want bold and thick fraction line.

Comment: Can you show html content having your #jax element?

Comment: jax element is <div id ="jax"> $y$ this , $cfrac~~~~$ </div> this

Comment: Try to inspect exact divide  ("-") sign from browser and apply css for bold.

Comment: fraction line is Mathjax shape, so css bold is not possible apply.<span class="math-tex"></span><span class="MathJax" id="MathJax-Element-6-Frame" tabindex="-1"></span></span><span style="display: inline-block; width: 0px; height: 2.159em;"></nobr></span><script type="math/tex" id="MathJax-Element-6">\cfrac{{3}}{{4}}</script></span>  html these shape

Comment: Is the Mathjax is js plugin? there may have provision to change font size in their api.

Comment: yes, mathjax is js plugin.   and i found change size method.   people recommend this font-size method.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086152/changing-mathjaxs-font-size

Comment: Good, best of luck!