# Changing MathJax's font size on Anki

Tags: latex, mathjax, anki

I've been using Anki with MathJax for some months now but the font size is incredibly small on desktop (it is fine on AnkiDroid, though). I got around it by using \huge every time I use MathJax, but that obviously isn't the best solution. It also makes everything too big on mobile.

My MathJax is configured as in [this post](https://niklaskorz.de/2017/06/studying-mathematics-with-anki-and-mathjax.html). I've searched how to edit MathJax's scaling and font size but nothing worked ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086152/changing-mathjaxs-font-size?rq=1)), it mostly ended just breaking it.

```
MathJax.Hub.processSectionDelay = 0;
MathJax.Hub.Config({
extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],    
    showProcessingMessages:false,
    tex2jax:{
        inlineMath: [['$','$']],
        displayMath:[['$$','$$']],
        processEscapes:true
    }
});
```

Also, my card's settings:

```
.card {
font-family: arial;
font-size: 20px;
text-align: center;
color: black;
background-color: white;
}

.cloze {
font-weight: bold;
color: blue;
}
```

Default size (too small) and \huge (more reasonable):

[image: default size and \huge]

I know this should be easy. Maybe greatly reducing MathJax's scaling, if that's possible.

EDIT: Alistair Martin basically solved it (both desktop and AnkiDroid are fine). It's working this way:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.processSectionDelay = 0;
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  messageStyle: 'none',
  showProcessingMessages: false,
  tex2jax: {
    inlineMath: [['$', '$']],
    displayMath: [['$$', '$$']],
    processEscapes: true
  },
  SVG: {
    scale: (!!navigator.userAgent.match(/(mac)|(mobile)/i) ? 100 : 180)
  }
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
  if (window.MathJax != null) {
    var card = document.querySelector('.card');
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub, card]);
    return;
  }
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_SVG';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
})();
    </script>
```

Comment: Live sample please.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that. But I included an image.

Comment: Do you have a link to a live page? It's very likely a problem of the particular context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what has worked for me so far:

1. Change to SVG. This means changing the url parameter to `?config=TeX-MML-AM_SVG`, as mentioned in [the article](https://niklaskorz.de/2017/06/studying-mathematics-with-anki-and-mathjax.html) you linked.
2. Change the JS script at the beginning of your card/s to include a SVG scale, whose value is based on the device

Something like this:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.processSectionDelay = 0;
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  messageStyle: 'none',
  showProcessingMessages: false,
  tex2jax: {
    inlineMath: [['$', '$']],
    displayMath: [['$$', '$$']],
    processEscapes: true
  },
  SVG: {
    scale: (!!navigator.userAgent.match(/(mac)|(mobile)/i) ? 100 : 180)
  }
});
</script>
```

^ here 100 is the % scale for Ankidroid & macOS, and 180 is the % scale for Windows.

Comment: This is really neat. Working as intended. Also, MathJax was _loading_, so I kinda ignored the part where he mentions SVG...