# MathJax Universal Font Size (Changing the Normal Text)

Tags: html, fonts, mathjax

I currently use MathJax as a teacher, and I love it! The issue I am having using MathJax when creating lessons is that the font size tends to be rather small. I need something that makes the text larger for all my students to read it (especially those who need large text for visual reasons).

Note I did ask a similar question before about font size [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67561862/mathjax-font-size). The issue with the answer doing it this way is that you have to wrap \text{ } and use html headers `<p> </p>` around everything you want to make text larger. This makes it really hard on me as a teacher wrapping all my text this way that I want larger. I know in LaTeX there was a way to make the math equations and normal text all be large by simply writing `\{LARGE}`. I am looking for something that does this.

> Is there a way to make everything be large without using headers, using a text functions, etc.? It makes it really difficult to use MathJax when you have to type `<h1> Let $f(x)=x^2$ </h1>` versus being able to type `Let $f(x)=x^2$` where all the text is large without having to do anything extra every single time you need that text to be larger.

I have used `chtml: {scale: 2}, svg: {scale: 2},` but it doesn't change the normal text. I feel like I am missing one thing! Below is an example of making $\textbf{ }$ and the math portion to get large. The normal text is still small.

[image]

Comment: Note none of the answers here I believe do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086152/changing-mathjaxs-font-size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MathJax's configuration only affects the output from MathJax, not other text on your page, as you have noticed.  This is the indented effect of those configuration parameters.  You control the size of the text on your page through the CSS for the page.  For example

```html
<style>
body {
  font-size: 200%;
}
</style>
```

would make *everything* on the page twice as big.  That is outside of MathJax's role, and is something that the page CSS should handle.

PS, You should not use `$\text{..}$` for non-mathematics content, as you have done for "leading coefficient".  That is part of the text of the page, not mathematics, so should not be processed by MathJax.